# Aligning a responsive div center

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Within the structure below what is the best way to be able to align the `div#logo` into the middle of the `grid_12 visible` div for only non mobile devices.

Can I create a custom piece of code to override the above classes?

I have created a Plunker with my code - http://plnkr.co/edit/lrRm0nXdYaz5g7dYe4DS

**HTML:**

```
<header class="row visible">

    <div class="grid_12 visible">
        <div class="row logo-wrap">

            <!-- logo -->
                        <div class="grid_6">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="http://dev.jzm.co.nz/mytime/"><img src="http://dev.jzm.co.nz/mytime/image/data/logo-black-web.png" title="My Time Candles" alt="My Time Candles" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- search -->
            <div class="grid_6 visible">
                <div id="search">
                    <div class="button-search">Search</div>
                                        <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="Search ... " onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
                                    </div><!--/search-->
            </div>

        </div><!--/row-->  
    </div><!--/grid_12-->
</header><!--End Header-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the div with the id of logo a width and set its margin-left and margin-right css properties to auto.. also setting a max-width to 100% will ensure the responsive behaviour..

```
#logo{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px; /* Original width of the logo image */ 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

and i hope you have already done this but..

```
#logo img{ 
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

UPDATE:

Modify your markup like so

```
<div id="container-top">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="http://dev.jzm.co.nz/mytime/"><img src="http://dev.jzm.co.nz/mytime/image/data/logo-black-web.png" title="My Time Candles" alt="My Time Candles"></a>
    </div>
<!-- search -->
    <div id="search" class="visible">
        <div class="button-search">Search</div>
        <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="Search ... " onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';">
    </div>
<!--/search-->
</div>

#container-top{
    position: relative;
}

#search{
    top: 15%;
    right: 0;
}
```

But then you'll have to use media queries to adjust your #search css as layout changes..
Also i have made some CSS changes above (before update section)..

Comment: Thanks,  But when I make it any bigger then 300px it goes back to left aligned why?  I want it centered in the middle of the `grid_12 visible` div

Comment: See link in question - http://plnkr.co/edit/lrRm0nXdYaz5g7dYe4DS or http://dev.jzm.co.nz/mytime/

Comment: For me it works fine.. it is always centered with the answer i gave

Comment: if you want it to be centered inside the `red background` as well when you set height more than the logo image's original height then add `text-align: center` to `#logo`

Comment: I get http://d.pr/i/YJBZ I want it centered in the middle of the div that holds the logo and the search

Comment: you have the logo inside `grid_6` which restricts the width of the container that contains the logo.. hence the logo is not centered with respect to the full width of the page but only inside `grid_6`

Comment: Yes but that is center of the #logo div I want to move it into the middle of the white space http://d.pr/i/94hd so its aligned center of the whole website

Answer (score 3):

Only you have to write one line `margin: 0 auto;`

```
#logo
{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```